# Crossy road disco elephant character

Tags: crossy-road

Does anyone know how to unlock the disco elephant on crossy road? I have heard rumors of this secret character and I have unlocked the crab character but I am unsure of how to unlock the elephant.

Answer (score 2):

It's called Disco Zoo - unlocks from the gum ball machine as per any other normal character (not a mystery one)

See video here:

Comment: Thanks I knew about that one but I thought there was another one similar to it. Probably not though. Do you have the crab?